# Saving HTML page as .php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Right now I just have a simple HTML page and a Javascript before the `</body>` tag. Is it ok to save this page as .php and everything would work fine? I couldn't find an explanation while searching. Can someone explain, why is it ok to save an HTML page as .php?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about a file located on your web server, sure: it'll work. Any non-PHP code (in this case the entire file) is served as is. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will be fine. PHP only processes things within `<?php ?>` tags.

But why don't you just try it and see if it works? It would take you far less time than asking a question.

Comment: because I wanted to know why/how it would work mainly :p thanks guys!

Comment: +1 for asking. Experimenting is good (and you should definitely experiment), but asking is good too, otherwise there could be unusual circumstances in which something fails to work, and you can't work out why. For the record, saving html files as .php because PHP was designed to be fitted into, and add extra functionality into existing HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

Anything not included within PHP tags will be left "as is", so there's no problem doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As an interesting and relevant aside; entire segments of a HTML site can be saved as separate PHP files and then brought into the website to form a whole. A good example is having one HTML navigation menu template which needs editing only once and, through PHP includes, updates on every page of your website.

Many popular websites and blogs use such a system for both convenience and consistency. In short, it is good practise to save segments of HTML code in this way.